# Replacing processor on a motherboard. Any restrictions?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade

When I replace the processor module to a compatable one with a motherboard,  are there any restrictions that I should follow?
I will clean install the os and don't need any of the data I have currently. I use this motherboard, g33t-m2.  Point out generally what I should think about and do , please.  Video cards, other PCI devices, ram, HDD, or some.

Comment: Even if the CPU socket is the same, it doesn't hurt to double check the specifications of the motherboard to see that the CPU is supported. Some motherboards might even need a BIOS update.

Comment: I would add one, remove old thermal paste and put new(check it's fresh, not older than 1 year)

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer of your motherboard - [Elitegroup Computer Systems](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=805&MenuID=16&LanID=0#fragment-SPEC) - mentions these specifications:

> **CPU**
>
> - LGA775 socket for latest Intel® Core 2 Quad(95W) / Core 2 Duo / Pentium Dual-Core (E21XX) / Celeron 4XX series processor
> - Supports Intel 45nm Core 2 Quad(Yorkfield) and Core2 Duo(Wolfdale) series processors. (please refer to the CPU support list for more detail)
> - FSB 1333/1066/800 MHz
>
> **Memory**
>
> - Dual-channel DDR2 memory architecture
> - 4 x 240-pin DDR2 DIMM socket support up to 8 GB
> - Support DDR2 800/667 DDR SDRAM
>
> Due to the operating system limitation, the actual memory size may be less than 4GB for the reservation for system usage under Windows® 32-bit OS.
>   For Windows® 64-bit OS with 64-bit CPU, there is no such limitation

Added:
You can install any of the CPUs listed (in the CPU list) and expect it to operate at the specification. If you put in a faster CPU, then you may be able to operate it at the faster speed (the bios may limit the speed), but you may get data errors. You shouldn't need to reinstall the OS (I didn't when I upgraded), but you may need to get a new Key for Windows due to a change in hardware.

Comment: I know of it. Just do I try it? Any information?